# GCP: ERROR: (gcloud.services.enable) PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission when enabling API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, api-gateway, google-cloud-api-gateway

I am trying to use API Gateway, and I am not able to enable the apigateway.googleapis.com API.
It is not shown in `gcloud services list`. I am trying to follow the instruction of gcp doc. https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/configure-dev-env#enabling_required_services

When trying to enable it in console, it does not return anything.

When trying to enable it in gcloud, it returns error as follows.
`gcloud services enable apigateway.googleapis.com ERROR: (gcloud.services.enable) PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission`

I was not able to attach a role since I was not able to find which role is related to apigateway.
I could not create custom role since there was no related policy.

Is there any way I can resolve this issue?

Comment: What are your role on the project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable "[API Gateway API](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/reference/rest)" you need at least [one of roles listed below](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/configure-dev-env#prerequisites):

- Owner
- Editor
- Service Config Editor

Next to [enable the service](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/configure-dev-env#enabling_required_services) you need to run:

```
gcloud services enable apigateway.googleapis.com
gcloud services enable servicemanagement.googleapis.com
gcloud services enable servicecontrol.googleapis.com
```

And the output should look somewhat like this:

```
wb@cloudshell:~ (wojtek)$ gcloud services enable apigateway.googleapis.com
Operation "operations/acf.f02abf75-b8c8-xxxx-b639-d1e69ed2c4c5" finished successfully.

wb@cloudshell:~ (wojtek)$ gcloud services enable servicemanagement.googleapis.com
Operation "operations/acf.faab3e15-7eb2-xxxx-8b34-2073f7f3518f" finished successfully.

wb@cloudshell:~ (wojtek)$ gcloud services enable servicecontrol.googleapis.com
Operation "operations/acf.faab3e15-7eb2-xxxx-8b34-2073f7f3518f" finished successfully.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually, I already had Owner for my service account, but I succeeded after adding 'Service Config Editor'. It returns 'No change - member already exists on the policy' but it works.